# Nginx not routing the request properly

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name http://localhost;
    server_tokens off;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location = /home {
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    location = /user {
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
     location = /login {
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
     location = /signup {
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

    location ^~\/verify\/\?token=([A-Za-z0-9-_]*\.[A-Za-z0-9-_]*\.[A-Za-z0-9-_]*$) {
        proxy_pass 'http://localhost:8000';
        }

     location ~ "^\/([0-9a-zA-Z+=-]{7,})$" {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass 'http://localhost:8000';
        }
}
```

I have this nginx.conf file, I want to route /verify/?token=something.something.something(the value of token is jwt) to the backend.

But getting 404 error while trying to access the endpoint, all other routes are working properly.

Comment: You can't check query part of the URL with `location` or `rewrite` directives, them both works with so-called _normalized_ URI whis does not include query part. If you want to pass any URL other than `/home`, `/user`, `/login` or `/signup` to the backend, just use `location / { proxy_set_header ... proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; }` instead of last two locations.

Comment: I did that, but getting the 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: @IvanShatsky `location ~ "^\/([0-9a-zA-Z+=-\?\/-_]{7,})$" { ... }` This solved the issue for me, but when I'm adding a .(dot) in the regex then again it's not working. can you please explain this part.

Comment: As I already said, normalized URI does not include the query part. When you got a request like `/verify/?token=ab.cd.ef`, normalized URI is `/verify/` and as you can see, it doesn't contain any dots or question signs.